What is denakereba (でなければ) here

あのレストランには、上着を着て行かなくてはいけませんか。
いいえ、Tシャツでなければ上着を着て行かなくてもかまいません。

I don't get the use of denakereba here, is it ba form of でない (でありません) or else?

What is your understanding of the sentence with it as the ば form of でない? Do you have a guess at what that would mean / is there something about it that confuses you?

Yes if it were like that tshirtを着なければ it would've been easy, I don't get the whole clause here "Tシャツでなければ". Use of de particle , and why use arimasu here and all

Are you familiar with ではない/じゃない etc?

Yes I do know that 。 also a form of です is   also used as である。

Yes, it's the conditional form of でない.

Tシャツでない
it's not a T-shirt
Tシャツでなければ
if it's not a T-shirt
Tシャツでなければ上着を着て行かなくてもかまいません
If it's not a jacket, it's no problem even if you don't go wearing a jacket.
→ As long as you're not wearing a T-shirt, you don't need to wear a jacket.

